# How to pass all rows and go calculation in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

How can I write in postgresql a function which for each row in a table takes the parameter in "agg_id" column and do some calculations?

In:

```
FOR r IN SELECT * FROM foo
```

what the r is?

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained yourself a bit. What's `agg_id` and where'd it come from? What calculations? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess from a rather unclear question:

```
DECLARE
   r record;
BEGIN
   FOR r IN SELECT * FROM foo
   LOOP
       RAISE NOTICE 'agg_id is %', r.agg_id;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

See [the PL/PgSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html).

Note that it's almost always better to use plain SQL, but it's hard for me to make useful suggestions about how with the total lack of information in the question.